# Fullcalendar Rails 3.2 - PG::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i'm try fullcalendar for my application with rails 3.2 and using postgresql for dbms.
to the point,

on model event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :all_day, :ends_at, :description, :name, :starts_end

  scope :between, lambda {|start_time, end_time|
    {:conditions => ["? < starts_at < ?", Event.format_date(start_time), Event.format_date(end_time)] }
  }

  # need to override the json view to return what full_calendar is expecting.
  # http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/
  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :name => self.name,
      :description=> self.description || "",
      :start => starts_at.rfc822,
      :end => ends_at.rfc822,
      :allDay => self.all_day,
      :recurring => false,
      :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.event_path(id),
      #:color => "red"
    }

  end

  def self.format_date(date_time)
    Time.at(date_time.to_i).to_formatted_s(:db)
  end

end
```

for starts_at and ends_at i'm using date type (not datetime)

on events.js.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar
    editable: true,
    header:
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    defaultView: 'month',
    height: 500,
    slotMinutes: 30,

    eventSources: [{
      url: '/admin'+'/events',
    }],

    timeFormat: 'h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ',
    dragOpacity: "0.5"

    eventDrop: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) ->
      updateEvent(event);

    eventResize: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) ->
      updateEvent(event);


updateEvent = (the_event) ->
  $.update "/events/" + the_event.id,
    event:
      name: the_event.name,
      starts_at: "" + the_event.start,
      ends_at: "" + the_event.end,
      description: the_event.description
```

on controller admin/events_controller.rb

```
def index
    @events = Event.scoped
    @events = Event.between(params['start'], params['end']) if (params['start'] && params['end'])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @events }
    end
  end
```

First, I insert an event and successfully and when run to localhost:3000/admin/events/ I get the following error such as

```
      Event Load (14.0ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE ('2012-11-25 00:00:
    00' < starts_at < '2013-01-06 00:00:00')
    PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "<"
    LINE 1: ...events"  WHERE ('2012-11-25 00:00:00' < starts_at < '2013-01...
                                                                 ^
    : SELECT "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE ('2012-11-25 00:00:00' < starts_at < '2
    013-01-06 00:00:00')
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 100ms

    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "<"
    LINE 1: ...events"  WHERE ('2012-11-25 00:00:00' < starts_at < '2013-01...
                                                                 ^
    : SELECT "events".* FROM "events"  WHERE ('2012-11-25 00:00:00' < starts_at < '2
    013-01-06 00:00:00')):
```

**Update**

change condition with

```
{:conditions => [
  "starts_at > ? and starts_at < ?",
  Event.format_date(start_time), Event.format_date(end_time)
] }
```

and on command promnt

```
 Event Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (starts_at > '2012-1
-25 00:00:00' and starts_at < '2013-01-06 00:00:00')
ompleted 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 15.0ms | ActiveRecord: 12.0ms)
```

but event not showing in calendar :(

**Update 2**

i'm try example app from
and event display.

```
Started GET "/events?start=1353776400&end=1357405200&authenticity_token=rTzzn2j+
DpUwKRwjPAdSjfq17glTu8dFjrKo2dGbEo8=&_=1355566671618" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-1
5 17:17:51 +0700
Processing by EventsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"start"=>"1353776400", "end"=>"1357405200", "authenticity_token"=
>"rTzzn2j DpUwKRwjPAdSjfq17glTu8dFjrKo2dGbEo8=", "_"=>"1355566671618"}
  ←[1m←[36mEvent Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE ('2
012-11-25 00:00:00' < starts_at < '2013-01-06 00:00:00')←[0m
Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 31.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

note : resource event

and this my app

```
Started GET "/admin/events?start=1353776400&end=1357405200&_=135556713595
4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-15 17:25:36 +0700
Processing by Admin::EventsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"start"=>"1353776400", "end"=>"1357405200", "_"=>"1355567135954"}
 Admin Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "public"."admins".* FROM "public"."ad
mins" WHERE "public"."admins"."id" = 25 LIMIT 1
  Account Load (6.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WH
ERE "public"."accounts"."admin_id" = 25 LIMIT 1
  Event Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (starts_at > '2012-1
1-25 00:00:00' and starts_at < '2013-01-06 00:00:00')
Completed 200 OK in 101ms (Views: 72.0ms | ActiveRecord: 24.0ms)
```

note : resource event under namespace admin ( admin/event ) , and i have multitenant of schema, admin use public schema to login an after login change to other schema (subdomain).

i change type date to datetime

on psql

```
education_development=# SELECT * FROM subdomain.events WHERE (starts_at > '2
012-11-25 00:00:00' and starts_at < '2013-01-06 00:00:00')
education_development-# ;
 id |     name      |       starts_at        |        ends_at         | all_day
|   description    |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+---------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------
+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | New Year 2013 | 2013-01-01 00:00:00+07 | 2013-01-01 00:00:00+07 | f
| New Year 2013 | 2012-12-15 06:53:50.695456 | 2012-12-15 06:53:50.695456
(1 row)
```

Can anyone help me? 
thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't but something like:

```
a < starts_at < b
```

in a WHERE clause, that's just not valid SQL. You can, however, put:

```
starts_at > a AND starts_at < b
```

You probably want:

```
{:conditions => [
  "starts_at > ? and starts_at < ?",
  Event.format_date(start_time), Event.format_date(end_time)
] }
```

BTW, the recommended approach for scopes with arguments is to [use a class method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments):

> Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes.

So you probably want:

```
def self.between(start_time, end_time)
  where('starts_at > :lo and starts_at < :up',
    :lo => Event.format_date(start_time),
    :up => Event.format_date(end_time)
  )
end
```

Comment: sorry it's my fault, apparently naming: starts_end should be: starts_at

Comment: But the error message is telling you that PostgreSQL doesn't like things of the form `a < b < c`.

Comment: i have change with your condition, but event not showing on calendar.

Comment: when get starts_at > '2012-1
-25 00:00:00' and starts_at < '2013-01-06 00:00:00'

on database starts_at only date not with time, does this effect?

Comment: You should probably remove the time of day part to avoid possible time one issues. And why would you expect your date to show? What happens if you try the query in `psql` or if you check the query output in he Rails console?

Comment: i try on psql, it's successfully.
i really confuse

Comment: ok, the first problem (pg error) solved.. maybe, events not showing are issue fullcalendar. thank's bro..